# Facebook notification when event happens on my server

Tags: java, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, web

I'm new to FB API, and I'm completely lost through variety of them. I have Java web app, and FB login to it on my site. How can I send notification to user, when some event happens (for example, his good arrived, and we want to notify him)?
Should I use Cavans application, or Graph API? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/notifications

> Currently, only apps on Facebook.com can use App Notifications. Notifications are only surfaced on the desktop version of Facebook.com.

Meaning, App Notifications are for Page Apps or Canvas Apps and you can send them with an App Access Token to every user who authorized your App. I suggest reading the whole article in the Facebook docs, there are some important rules and a lot of important information.